# Unexpected keyword_end error, yet syntax seems fine

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

This function is supposed to pull names from a Comma Separated Values file, and place them into an array.

```
def xprt_csv_to_ary(csv_file)
    namecatcher_regex = "/^[\.{1}]([A-Z]+)\.{3}/" # Matches up to char before next name
    current_word = 0
    names_array = []
    while current_word < 5000
        if current_word == 0
            name = csv_file.readline.match(namecatched_regex)
        else
            name = csv_file.past_match.match(namecatcher_regex)
        end
        names_array[current_word] = name
        current_word ++
    end
    return names_array
end
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
```

I would be as happy to be referred to an existing question that solves my problem as to have someone answer me directly.

Comment: The error message in your title and in the question don't match up. Which is it? Is there a *missing* `end` or one too many?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error comes from line:

```
current_word ++
```

There's no such syntax in Ruby. It should be:

```
current_word += 1
```

What's more, you create your regexp incorrectly. It should be:

```
namecatcher_regex = /^[\.{1}]([A-Z]+)\.{3}/
```

There may be some other errors that I didn't notice.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I think I can take it from here. :)

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
current_word ++
```

You are telling Ruby to add something to `current_word`, but you never tell it *what* to add, instead there's an `end` directly on the next line. You are missing the operand to the unary `+`. It should be something like

```
current_word + something_else
```

or

```
current_word + +something_else
```

In Ruby, whitespace is allowed around operators, so

```
a + 
b
# equivalent to a + b, which is equivalent to a.+(b)
```

and even

```
+ 
a
# equivalent to +a, which is equivalent to a.+@()
```

is perfectly fine, so if you combine the two, you get that

```
a + + 
b
# equivalent to a + +b, which is equivalent to a.+(b.+@())
```

is also perfectly fine, and since whitespace around operands is perfectly fine but optional,

```
a+b
```

and

```
a ++ 
b
# equivalent to a + +b as above
```

is also perfectly fine.

That's why you only get the error on the *next* line with the `end`, because only there can Ruby tell that you are missing the operand to the unary prefix `+` operator.