# Ruby Syntax error at lines 18,39

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement, syntax, ping

I can't figure out my syntax error on lines 18,39

I keep reading that my format is wrong, I just don't know why it says this. This code may not be efficient but I want to get this to at least work for now.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

require 'net/ping'

missed_pings = 0
logFile = ""
router = Net::Ping::External.new("www.google.com")


def check_ping(host, logFile)
    missed_pings = 0
    server = Net::Ping::External.new(host)

    for i in 0..15
        if not server.ping 
            missed_pings++

=====> end

    if missed_pings < 15 then
        logFile.concat("#{host} +\n")
    else
        logFile.concat("#{host} -\n")
    end

    if missed_pings == 15 then
        #email(logFile)
        puts logFile
    end
end

while router.ping
    # check_ping(ARGV[0])
    check_ping("10.0.1.1", logFile)
    check_ping("192.168.100.1", logFile)
    check_ping("10.0.1.1", logFile)
    check_ping("www.google.com", logFile)
====> end
```

Comment: You are missing one `end`

Comment: @Grych, I added an end for the if statement within the for loop, still an error

Comment: Ups, sorry. Obviously, missed_pings++ - ++ doesnt exists in Ruby

Comment: This question has been asked many many many many times before, almost on a daily basis. I'd really like to know which book or tutorial teaches this, so that it can be eradicated once and for all!

Comment: @JörgWMittag tbh I've just gotten the habit from Java and using it there. Not sure if it is allowed in python cause I've used that

Answer (score 1):

First at all, you missed one `end`. Second, `missed_pings++` is not valid construct in Ruby, you should change it to `missed_pings += 1`, so:

```
for i in 0..15
    if not server.ping 
        missed_pings += 1
    end
end
```

Comment: `missed_pings++` *is* a perfectly valid construct in Ruby, that's *why* the error message is seemingly misleading! See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24953993/2988) to the duplicate question for why and how it is (or can be) valid, and why you don't simply get a "there is no `++` operator" error. (BTW: Ruby IDEs should really warn about this, I'm surprised why they don't.)